# Safari 11's new autoplay restrictions on HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-audio

I'm trying to figure out how Safari 11's (and iOS') autoplay restrictions are implemented and I don't understand why the following doesn't start playing the audio file:

```js
/*
    Call stack, this doesn't work 
*/

const btn = document.createElement('BUTTON')
const textLabel = document.createTextNode('Play')
const audio = new window.Audio()
audio.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/master/mp3/winamp.mp3'
// audio.controls = true

btn.appendChild(textLabel)
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(btn)
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(audio)

btn.onclick = e => {
  window
    .fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/contents/mp3/modem-sound.mp3`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => {
      audio.src = json.download_url
      audio.play()
    })
}
```

```html
<div id='root'/>
```

Whereas Safari is fine with the following:

```js
/*
    Call stack, using a fake Promise. This works 
*/

const btn = document.createElement('BUTTON')
const textLabel = document.createTextNode('Play')
const audio = new window.Audio()
audio.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/master/mp3/modem-sound.mp3'
// audio.controls = true

btn.appendChild(textLabel)
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(btn)
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(audio)

const mockedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/master/mp3/winamp.mp3'
    return resolve(src)
  }, 500)
})

btn.onclick = (e) => {
  mockedPromise.then(src => {
    audio.src = src
    audio.play()
  })
}
```

```html
<div id='root'/>
```

Does anybody know how Safari determines whether something is an autoplay or not? I'm not looking for a work around (starting and pausing helps for instance) but I'm trying to figure out how this works.

(some more background information on Safari's new autoplay policy can be found here: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)

Comment: I'm noticing my website, which uses subtle sound effects, no longer plays them. They are not auto-play, they play upon completion of a task, activated by javascript.

Comment: Now that's a sound I've not heard in a long time.

Comment: I believe this may be because your trying to initiate an auto play on a mobile device. (given you posted in the title iOS)

W3C speficies that auto play should not work on mobile devices as a result of mobile data charges a user could be susceptible to

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your algorithm from

`user clicks -> loads audio information -> changes source -> play`

to

`user clicks -> changes source -> play`

Basically you need to change `src` in `audio` and start playback right after user clicks play button.

iOS prevents autoplay when intermediary fetching is present.

Answer (score 0):

**Autoplay**

```
audio.autoplay = true;
```

Please note that with mobile devices W3C have specified the user must trigger the playback in order to avoid mobile data charges.

Therefore with mobile devices, you will need to present the user with the button to trigger the autoplay.

```js
const btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
const textLabel = document.createTextNode('Play');
const audio = new window.Audio();
audio.src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/master/mp3/modem-sound.mp3';
audio.autoplay = true;
// audio.controls = true

btn.appendChild(textLabel)
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(audio);

const mockedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const src = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnglst/autoplay-tutorial/master/mp3/winamp.mp3';
    return resolve(src);
  }, 500);
})

btn.onclick = (e) => {
  mockedPromise.then(src => {
    audio.src = src;
    audio.play();
  })
}
```

```html
<div id='root'/>
```